# Sorted list of two query sets

Tags: django, union, django-queryset

```
class TagSynonym(models.Model):
    source_tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    target_tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name='tag_synonyms', null=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    used_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-used_count', 'name')
```

For a given query `q`:
I want all the tags which contain the query in its name or in the related synonym's source_tag_name.
I also want the sort order to be preserved by `ordering`.

I have a query like the following

```
    tags_by_name = tag_all.filter(name__contains=q)
    tags_by_synonyms = tag_all.select_prefetched('tag_synonyms').filter(tag_synonyms__source_tag_name__contains=q).distinct()
    tags = tags_by_name | tags_by_synonyms
    tags = tags.distinct()
```

I'm not sure if the above code is correct. 
Are there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Django [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = Tag.objects.select_prefetched('tag_synonyms').filter(
    Q(name__contains=q) | Q(tag_synonyms__source_tag_name__contains=q)) \
    .distinct()
```